# Cracking the coding interview - Number Swapper Problem

Tags: algorithm

In the book, "Cracking the coding interview", there is a problem in the 16th chapter called "Number Swapper".

Can anyone explain highlighted line in below image?

[image]

I have tried this problem using addition & subtraction method with a double data type, which is working fine. apart from that, the string will not work in xor.

So what does it mean by it works for more datatypes than just integers? Which datatype will give a problem with the addition-subtraction approach?

Comment: Please provide as much of this as possible as *text*, not as image.

Comment: In most real word scenarios, we will be using integers only for swapping using bit manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't tested enough with floats and doubles.

If you try the addition/subtraction solution with floats 1. and 10'000'000. you will get back 10'000'000 and 0 (because representation limitations). Xor should work just fine in this case as well. Same issue with doubles but you will need larger difference between the numbers (1. and 1e16 i think). Some languages have special representations that might deal with these cases.

For strings you would need to make both of them equal in length and then apply xor byte-by-byte.

All in all, bit-wise xor will give you correct answers in all cases where you can apply it.

Comment: ... unless the `a` and `b` are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The `XOR` solution works for anything represented with bits, to wit, any data in a binary computer.  Data types that have troubles with the sub-add-sub method include

- any type with over- or under-flow characteristics, e.g. integers
- any type with precision characteristics, e.g. floats
- any type without those operations defined in some arithmetic cognate, e.g. strings